# sqlite3 verbose logging in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am facing a weird issue where connection.commit() is taking whooping 15 seconds to finish.
I need to enable debugging messages of Sqlite3 in Python to find out what is causing this long running operation.
All I know is my python process is in 'D' state i.e. waiting for I/O to finish.

sqlite3_config() seems to offer debugging messages in C.
Is there a Python equivalent for this ?

Also is the a way to redirect the debugging logs to syslog ?

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to set up an [error log](https://www.sqlite.org/errlog.html) callback function in Python?

Comment: No. Error log will be invoked only in case of an error (correct me if wrong). 
What I am looking for is some verbose logging from Sqlite3.
For example, /var/log/syslog has logging for say dnsmasq service in linux.
Updated question title.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you're looking for, maybe

```
sqlite3.enable_callback_tracebacks(True)
```

from https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html